# How to show Work items progress percentage in azure devops dashboard?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, dashboard

How to show the Work items progress percentage graph in the azure DevOps dashboard?

I am trying to create a work item progress percentage in the Azure DevOps dashboard.

I am able to create Work item Count only in the dashboard but I want to create Work items Progress

So is there any query for that or else is there any extensions for that

Comment: some one Please help me

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I think what you expect may be a widget like [Query tile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tmmb4.png) to directly show the progress percentage of the work item in the query you chose.

[image]

Currently I'm afraid there's no widget that can meet your requirement. But here're some widgets that may serve as a workaround for you.

1.Since you want to track the progress of your work items, you could consider using the **Burndown chart**. You could see the completed percentage.

The burndown chart is used to track completion of a predefined scope of work over a predefined period of time. It shows the completed work and the remaining work on specific dates for the team you have configured in the configuration setting.
For your reference, you could find more details in this official doc: [Configure Burndown & Burnup widgets - Azure DevOps | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/configure-burndown-burnup-widgets?view=azure-devops).
[image]

2.You could also choose **Chart for Work Items**.
There're multiple kinds of charts you could choose in the widget. But you are not able to see the progress percentage directly. For your reference, you can find more details in the official doc: [Add Chart Widget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/charts?view=azure-devops#add-chart-widget).

[image]

At the same time, if you want this feature to improve, it is recommended for you to submit a suggestion ticket to suggest the feature on: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion
That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate product group and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions.

Comment: I need just percentage only

Comment: I‘m afraid there's no built-in or extension can help only show percentage of the progress of your work item. But I do find an extension  [Extended Sprint Overview Widget](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ninido.ninido-extended-sprint-overview-widget) that provides a bar-widget to visualize sprint progress. Hope it can help.